# How to stop file locking of .exe with a Sandbox Console Application, Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I literally think this is the only technical challenge I have been presented with that I have not figured out a way to solve to date.

Using Visual Studio 2012 proffessional, happens in Visual Studio 2010 as well, I use a simple ConsoleApplication to test code, complete coding tests, a scratch pad or Sandbox if you will. For the life of me I cannot stop the errors:

> **Error   12  Unable to copy file "obj\x86\Debug\ConsoleApplication.exe" to "bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication.exe' because it is being used by another process.    ConsoleApplication**

---

> **Error   11  Could not copy "obj\x86\Debug\ConsoleApplication.exe" to "bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.   ConsoleApplication1**

I have Process Explorer, every time I try and close the handle I get the following:

[image]

So every time I make a simple code change, after Main exits correctly my Console.Application.exe is locked and I have to just sit there and wait a minute or two to actually rebuild a code change and test.

Is there any way to stop this from happening, the Main thread handles disposal on its own, so attempting manual disposal, like Application.Exit is futile, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619668/how-do-i-correctly-exit-stop-dispose-a-console-application-in-c-sharp).

```
class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var numbers = GetUniqueRandoms(new Random(), 10, 100);

        Console.WriteLine("Numbers before selection sort:");
        foreach (var number in numbers)
        {
            Console.Write("{0},", number);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        //selection sort
        var pos_min = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < numbers.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            pos_min = i;
            for (var j = i + 1; j < numbers.Length; j++)
            {
                if (numbers[j] < numbers[i])
                    pos_min = j;
            }

            if (pos_min != i)
            {
                var temp = numbers[i];
                numbers[i] = numbers[pos_min];
                numbers[pos_min] = temp;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Numbers after selection sort:");
        foreach (var number in numbers)
        {
            Console.Write("{0},", number);
        }

    }

    static int[] GetUniqueRandoms(Random random, int count, int max)
    {
        var result = new List<int>(count);
        var set = new HashSet<int>();
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            int num;

            do
            {
                num = random.Next(1, max);
            } while (!set.Add(num));

            result.Add(num);
        }
        return result.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: I had issue with this a long time and ended making a pre-build script, that moves the exe into different location. Not a real solution, but worked.

Comment: this application never exits; the last statement is a perpetual `Console.Readline()`.  Are you saying that if you use CTRL+Z to send null and close the `Readline()`, the program still stays in memory?

Comment: The Console.Readline keeps the Console application window open so I can read the output, I hit enter/return, the application closes

Comment: I have removed the Console.ReadLine() and will report if that fixes anything when my .exe unlocks again in a minute or two.

Comment: Same file lock occurs with the Console.Readline() removed

Comment: @AntonínLejsek, don't you have to create a new distinct folder each time in your pre-build script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AntoninLejesk answer was a good try but didn't work for me. I found a great answer that worked here: [Visual Studio 2010 build file lock issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095573/visual-studio-2010-build-file-lock-issues)

You create a ConsoleApplication.exe called "VisualStudioLockWorkaround" and call the exe in your pre build script, passing the target path, worked like a charm, big up to @Godeke for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Not a real solution**

Ok, here is the pre-build script. The parsing of `%Time%` and `%Date%` depends on localization and maybe would not work for You. Key is the `move` command, assembly file is moved away and compiler is happy.

```
For /f "Tokens=2,3,4 Delims=/. " %%i In ("%Date%") Do @(
  Set Month=%%j& Set Day=%%i& Set Year=%%k
)

set ActDate=%Year%_%Month%_%Day%

For /f "Tokens=1,2,3 Delims=/.:, " %%i In ("%Time%") Do @(
  Set Hour=0%%i& Set Min=%%j& Set Sec=%%k
)

set ActTime=%Hour:~-2,2%-%Min%-%Sec%

move c:\\Users\\Antonˇn\\Desktop\\evidence\\EvidenceSolution\Evidence\bin\Debug\evidence.exe c:\\Users\\Antonˇn\\Desktop\\evidence\\garbage\%ActDate%__%ActTime%__evidenceDebug.exe
move c:\\Users\\Antonˇn\\Desktop\\evidence\\EvidenceSolution\Evidence\bin\Release\evidence.exe c:\\Users\\Antonˇn\\Desktop\\evidence\\garbage\%ActDate%__%ActTime%__evidenceRelease.exe

echo 0
```

Comment: A good idea, I got an error with the script thought, "exited with code 1". My file paths are good but you don't escape all back slashes in your file paths, how come?

Comment: It is copying Exes to my garabage folder, one build copies 3 exes, not sure why

Comment: Ok, I just added an EXIT 0 in place of echo 0 that is copying exes to my gabarage folder, and I can build and run my ConsoleApplication but I still get the unable to copy exe errors same as before

Answer (score 0):

Both of above discussed solutions didn't worked for me.
I don't know how but giving a restart to my pc saved my life.